# Using MIN IF function to find peaks and valleys in data

Tags: excel-formula, max, min

I have a cyclic data set. There are low cycles and high cycles, each with slightly different mins and maxes. i need to find the values of each min and max. I have attached picture of a simplified version of what I have. I know roughly what time the peak/valley will occur, so i thought i could use the min if function to isolate each extreme value. For example, it i wanted to find a valley between time 1 and time 5, i would use this formula:

=MIN(IF(1< time<5,data))

This just yields 0 for some reason. It sort of worked once but instead of isolating the minimum for the selected time period, it just found the minimum for the whole column. What am I doing wrong here? Is what i am trying to do possible without using VBA? This is a template for work that others will use and not everyone is able to use macro-enabled workbooks so I'd like to avoid that.

[image: Simplified Example]

Comment: what is "time" defined as ? I assumed it was a named cell ... is it a named "Range" ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
=MIN(IF(time>5,IF(time<12,data)))
```

It is an array formula and needs to be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: was going to say, that first one looked a bit over complicated :) lol.  That second one, simpler, however, try range 1 to 5 .. still comes back with 0 ??

Comment: @Ditto nope, came back with 8 which since I was searching greater than 1 and less than 5 is the correct answer with the numbers above.  The array formulas do not like AND

Comment: got it ... my bad issue at my end .. found/fixed it .. nice :)  I gotta learn me array formulas :) lol

Comment: Nice! thanks a lot for your help, I'm glad it turned out to be such an easy fix. Have a good weekend!